# 8-bit per cell memory?

Tags: memory, hardware, ram

I'm a software development student, who want to improve its hardware knowledge.

I'm reading [Structured Computer Organization by Tanenbaum](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0132916525). In the chapter 2, the author says the following:

> "[...] In recent years, nearly all computer manufacturers have standardized on an 8-bit cell [...]".

I thought this was correct, but searching over internet, I found there is no memories with 8-bit per cell!

So, my question is: Is it an error of the author or I misunderstood what he tried to explain? If so, what is, "usually", the number of bits per cell and how could I see the bits per cell of my memory?

Comment: I'm sure you don't mean "there are ***no*** memories with 8bit/cell": http://nl.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Alliance-Memory/AS4C128M8D3-12BCN/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMu4dzSHpcLNgpvOuBx3ocn4qtioA89ZG7ewF903h74kHA%3d%3d  And then there's EEPROM, FLASH, etc, there's 1000's!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be some confusion between memory organization (which is most often integer multiples of  8 bits wide) and bits per memory cell.

Storing more than one bit per cell can be achieved by storing an analog voltage that can be differentiated into \$2^n\$ different levels for \$n\$ bits. [MLC flash](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-level_cell) can have 2 or 3 bits per cell, requiring 4  or 8 levels. It becomes progressively more difficult and thus more prone to errors and bad yields as the number of bits increases.

Comment: There was/is an analogue IC storage system by ISD for message recorders that stored an analogue signal that could theoretically have been used to store 256 levels giving 8 bits per cell but it would have been unreliable except for analogue value storage.

Comment: As @KalleMP says - the ISD product (now some other name) is one of the few that genuinely does this. I have used their products for analog speech recording use (as they intend) and for that purpose it works very well.

Comment: @Russell I still have a few rails of the ISD parts left over from an advertising project years ago.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I have some too - 2590's I think - used in talking communication aids that I used to make.

Answer (score 4):

They must mean that a smallest addressable unit is 8 bits which is called a **byte** or sometimes they even call that smallest addressable unit as a cell.By grouping these cells you get a word.

So a 64 bit computer has **8 cells**/word.So in effect they are likely x8 systems

Answer (score 2):

This quotation seems to be using the word "cell" to mean an addressable storage location, where most of us would consider a cell to be a thing capable of storing one bit.

I don't know the vintage of that book, but older memory ICs were organized so that each addressable location would store 8 bits (1 byte, or memory word).

Comment: 1st edition 1974, the one he's reading most likely 1990-ish. Funny thing is, many systems still allow byte addressing. Whether it's fast or desirable on them is another thing.

Answer (score 1):

There are so many types of memory that is hard to answer.

What was "standardized" (wich standard ?) was the byte (octet) as a fundamental size on a computer. This means that, usually, computers have how to deal with 8 bit numbers, even if they are 32 bits. A byte is 8 bits anywhere, but the computer WORD might have other sizes, multiplies of a byte (ex.: 32bit word wich is composed of four bytes etc). It might even arrange those bytes in different orders (MSB first, LSB first etc).

But, on memories, you might find a lot of types. You might find a 8 bit EPROM, or a single bit RAM (where you need to group 8 ram chips to get a single byte, etc). Or even full 64bit memories that transfer 64bit words at a time.

But, even when all the memories have different word sizes, you can still ADDRESS all memories in 8bit boundaries.

For example :

If your "cell" was 32 bits, thats how the program would be stored in memory:

```
100 add r1, r2, r3
101 sub r3, r5, r1
102 br 100
```

If your "cell" is 8 bits, thats how it is stored in memory :

```
100 add r1, r2, r3
104 sub r3, r5, r1
108 br 100
```

In the past, some computers worked like the first example, having memories cells of 32bits (or 36, or 24 etc.), so, in that case, the "standardization" was to accept a single memory "cell" size (8bits) and work other sizes from that.

This does not mean that a computer cant access the RAM in lumps of other multiples of 8 bits (16, 32, 64, etc.). You might have instructions like

```
 MOV EAX, [BP+10000] // hipotetical, i dont know if this addressing mode exists
 // wich will transfer 4 bytes in a single cycle into the EAX.
```

But the BP+10000 in the instruction still sees the memory as made out of 8bit cells.